# How to get object value type from union of objects

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have these types:

```js
interface A {
  a: number
  b: string
  c: string
}

interface B {
  a: string
  b: string
}

type C = A | B
```

I want to get the possible values of the type `C`. For example

```js
type ValueOfObject<T, K> = What should be here?
type aValues = ValueOfObject<C, 'a'> // should return number | string
type bValue = ValueOfObject<C, 'b'> // should return string
type cValues = ValueOfObject<C, 'c'> //should return string | undefined
```

How can i achieve it?

I manage to get all the keys from union by

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T: never;
```

Cannot get the values though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T: never;

type ValueOfObject<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = 
  T extends infer U
    ? K extends keyof U
      ? T[K]
      : undefined
    : never
```

We distribute `T` over the conditional and check for each member `U` if `K extends keyof U`. If it does, we can return `T[K]` and if not, we add `undefined` to the union.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmRAFcBbAI2h2XMIGcwpQBzahexlrAXyy1EixEKAEKZqBZAyYhWuWlM6yefMAE8ADigDCyALxpkAH2QjVmlAGkIaugHkYAVRDAA9iAA8AFQB8+5F7IEAAekCAAJnQByAD8yADWNq4wAYQgEABu0ADc5lrIAGpwADbEEA525ABWEAhg3gA0yJZBoRARUda2Ds5unr5+BtSBIWGRyKAw0MiO1LhxLaPt44lqyTNzuLEBANqWALqbuITEERAwoBDhm2mZVFjq+XBFpRBRBi9lFdW19dpNAHI4AC-AB6UFSAAWrmIxXCyCgEDAxCgICIZEoUGMihkrEeKHInxQHxKXxglRqdQ8-2QAPIIOQ4KhMLhCKRKLR0i4+OQCCJ70KpPK5J+VJpAIQDPBdGhsPhiORqJxLGxp3C50u4SAA)

Comment: Yup this one would work too :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution:

```js
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T: never;
// We need to convert our union to intersection then our type would be trivial
type UnionToIntersection<T> =
  (T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never) extends
  (x: infer R) => any ? R : never;
type UnionValue<U, K extends KeysOfUnion<U>> = UnionToIntersection<U>[K];
```